# Magento sort regions by default_name

Tags: magento

I need to sort region drop down in one page checkout page. I found data coming from 'Mage_Directory_Helper_Data' I need to sort this data. I tried by adding below code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->getResourceCollection()
                    ->addCountryFilter($countryIds)
                        ->addOrder('default_name', 'DESC')
                    ->load();
```

But it did not work. Can anyone please help me. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
        if (empty($json)) {
            $countryIds = array();
            foreach ($this->getCountryCollection() as $country) {
                $countryIds[] = $country->getCountryId();
            }
            $collection = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->getResourceCollection()
                ->addCountryFilter($countryIds)
                ->setOrder('default_name','DESC')
                ->load();
            $regions = array(
                'config' => array(
                    'show_all_regions' => $this->getShowNonRequiredState(),
                    'regions_required' => $this->getCountriesWithStatesRequired()
                )
            );
            foreach ($collection as $region) {
                if (!$region->getRegionId()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $regions[$region->getCountryId()][$region->getRegionId()] = array(
                    'code' => $region->getCode(),
                    'name' => $this->__($region->getName())
                );
            }
            krsort($regions); // or ksort($regions)
            $json = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($regions);
        }
```